# SOQL for loop with less records - How to approach?

Tags: apex, soql, heap

We have a scenario where we need to query 2 large text area fields and add them as a response to an external system.

The source object on which these fields are present, we have used SOQL for loop to iterate through them and get required data, but even with SOQL for loop just querying data for 200 records results in us hitting more than 90% heap which fails the transactions afterwards. In total we may need to send these fields for 1000-2000 records of that object.

As a workaround what we have implemented is to loop through the records in limits of 40 and check for heap and do the concatenation. if we cross 80% heap we ask the external system to call again.

Basically custom SOQL for loop implementation. Is there a better way to do this and how should this be approached?

Comment: Does this need to be asynchronous, or could you switch to an async context (queueable, batchable) where you get twice the heap limits and ways to split the data into smaller chunks to avoid loading a lot of data in one go?

Comment: Basically, could you push the data out to the external system, instead of responding to a direct request?

Comment: BTW, your workaround seems OK as an actual solution; we do similar in some cases though what we specifically do is return an encoded "continuation" value that tells the server where it has gotten to in its previous processing. If there's a "continuation" value returned by the service, the client calls again. Once there's no continuation value the client knows it has all the data.

Comment: @PhilW, we are sending this data in response to initial callout we made. the external systems pulls these record ids and they call salesforce. if we have to do it through queueable  we will lose context of the thread and they will be waiting for the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that there's a maximum response size even if you didn't hit the heap limits (in fact, the response size is limited by heap size). As such, what you've got going on is probably the best way to approach your problem. That's presuming, of course, the external system can't just call a Salesforce API directly, which would be more ideal.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the point of using salesforce API. the external system can call salesforce API directly?

Comment: Salesforce provides standard REST APIs for querying data (as well as CRUD on records). This would not be able to concatenate long text areas though.

Comment: @PhilW, do you know the response size for a rest api ?

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm).

Comment: @RedDevil There's a [batch retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_retrieve.htm) that does what you want (at least, mostly). You can retrieve 2000 records by Id. You can also do a plain query to get the results, but you may have to deal with pagination (nextUrl will be set to the cursor for the remaining items, called in a loop). There's no need to get Apex involved here.